# Access services from docker swarm from public

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm with 2 nodes, running 4 services. 
The problem is I want to expose those 4 services through an public IP over port 80. I know I could use subdomain and proxy server to route traffic for each service, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're introducing a proxy server your services will need to listen to different ports. You can't have them all listen to 80.

If your services listen to different ports, they will be available through node1 or node2's ip address, no matter which node the service containers are on. Swarm will dns resolve your container on either node.

For instance, let's say you have serviceA listening to port 82 and that it only has 1 container running (1 task) on node2. Any request to node1:82 or node2:82 will be redirected to that container.